# How was Germany involved in the Russian Civil War after the Paris Peace Conference?

Tags: germany, communism, russian-civil-war, treaties

What was Germany's involvement in the Russian Civil War after the Paris Peace Conference? After signing the Treaty of Versailles, Germany's economy was pretty much in ruins, but which side of the Russian Civil War was Germany on after the Paris Peace Conference; did Germany support the Red Army or the White Army?

The White Army was supported by the Allies, which was an enemy of the Allies, so one would think Germany supported the Red Army. However, Germany didn't want Communism in it's country after the Paris Peace Conference, so it couldn't have supported the Red Army either. So which side did it support and what did Germany do to support that side in the Russian Civil War?

Comment: A more interesting question (post 11.11.1918) is the reverse: Involvement of Soviet Russia in German mini-Civil war(s): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spartacist_uprising, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bavarian_Soviet_Republic

Answer (score 3):

The Russian civil war was 1917-1922. In 1922 Germany and Russia signed the [Treaty of Rapallo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treaty_of_Rapallo_(1922)). Also, Germany had facilitated the transit of Lenin from his [exile in Switzerland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vladimir_Lenin#February_Revolution_and_the_July_Days:_1917) to Russia.

Keep in mind that Germany had a [Socialist government](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_Revolution_of_1918%E2%80%9319) from 1918; they remained strong in [1920](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_federal_election,_1920). While Socialists were feuding with the Communists, they were not exactly in favor of monarchies, wither.

Comment: The early years of the Weimar republic had a [centre-left to center-right government](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weimar_Coalition). I wouldn't call that socialist.

Comment: @MartinSchröder, I'm using socialist to describe the SPD. Getting into details of the splits of the leftist parties probably won't help the original poster.

Answer (score 3):

Germany did not interfere in the Russian civil war after the Paris conference.
Before the defeat, Germany helped Bolsheviks to seize power, and concluded the Brest treaty with them (separate peace). As a result of this treaty Germans occupied Ukraine. After the defeat, and Paris conference, they evacuated their troops from Ukraine, which made possible the conquest of the Ukraine by the Bolshevik Russia. In the later years both Bolsheviks and Germany were in international isolation, so they co-operated in many areas. But Germany did not really meddle in the Russian civil war.